# Filter out all elements in a jQuery result set that have a parent (at any level) with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to apply some jQueryUI functionality to elements all throughout my SPA, however I'm having trouble omitting elements contained in a certain parent. I'm not actually sure if jQuery can do what I'm asking right now.

The bit of relevant code:

```
function initializeControls($container) {
    var $context;

    if ($container != undefined)
        $context = $container;
    else
        $context = $("html");

    $context = //$context, but ignoring all .no-controls elements and ALL children

    //do stuff...
}
```

Simply put, I want all elements in `$context` where *no* parent element, first parent or otherwise, has the `.no-controls` class.

It sounds simple, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I've tried different combinations of `.find()`, `.filter()`, `.remove()`... but it never seems to do exactly what I need.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `closest()` in a `filter()`

```
var $filteredCollection = $context.filter(function(){
  return !$(this).closest('.no-controls').length;
});
```

`closest()` inspects the element itself and all ancestors

Comment: Hadn't considered using `closest()` because I've had problems with it in the past, but perhaps I wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: Question - why the `.length`? It worked, but I'm curious as to how.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].parents = function(a,i,m){
  return jQuery(a).parents(m[3]).length < 1 && !jQuery(a).is(m[3]);
};



$context.filter(':parents(.no-controls)')
```